# C# - Reference to object in list

Tags: c#

I have a problem with updating an object in a collection. I've got the following class structure:

```
class XYZ
{
    public static ObservableCollection<CustomObject> List =
        new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();

    public void OnOpen()
    {
    }

    public void OnMessage()
    {
    }
}
```

In the `OnOpen()` method I want to add the object to the list. Is there a way to keep a reference to this exact object so I can always update its properties without the need to look through the whole list?

I thought about saving it in a local property before I add it to the list like this:

```
private CustomObject obj;

//OnOpen
obj = new CustomObject();
List.Add(obj);
```

But that didn't work. Then I tried to add it as a pointer, but Visual Studio says it can't create a pointer from the managed Type `CustomObject`.

How do I get a reference to the object without first iterating through `List` to find it?

Comment: "But that didn't work." - What exactly didn't work? What were you expecting?

Comment: You usually don't use pointers in C#.

Comment: *But that didn't work.* - What do you mean? You can modify fields of the object after it has been added.

Comment: If I update a property of the obj, the obj in the collection still has the old value. So I want to keep a reference to this object.

Comment: Are you declaring the field outside of the method?  Are you using the class field or hiding it with a local variable?

Comment: Is `CustomObject` a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: You just want to keep a history of the old values?

Comment: Yeah usually. I'm not usually, and I think, it would be a much better solution to keep a reference instead of always iterating through the whole list.

Comment: CustomObject is a class.

Comment: I'm using a class field, not a local var.

Comment: `obj` should always reference the last item you added in `OnOpen`

Comment: There's not enough here to diagnose.  You need to show how you're using the `XYZ `class` and ideally provide a complete example that shows the incorrect results you describe.

Comment: can you store its index and get it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you try to achieve. If you need to keep a reference to an object just declare a variable and keep it. Where to keep the variable depends on your requirements which you haven't shared. Example:

```
class XYZ
{
    private CustomObject theObjectINeedAReferenceTo;

    public static ObservableCollection<CustomObject> List =
        new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();

    public void OnOpen()
    {
        theObjectINeedAReferenceTo = new CustomObject();
        List.Add(theObjectINeedAReferenceTo);
        ...
    }

    public void OnMessage()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Anywhere *within* the class you can access your object now. The access will be possible after the method `OnOpen()` was called. Also, the reference changes every time `OnOpen()` is called. The example above is not thread safe.

Comment: Yeah i already did that, but if I update a property of the CustomObject in OnMessage, the value in the Collection is still the old one.

Comment: You need to share this part of the code as well because what you say makes no sense. You sound like you got two objects, not just one, but you believe you deal with just one.

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach was correct. Quick worked example to show how you could do it. Light on best practice to avoid confusing the answer, if you can help it try to avoid static references.

```
public class CustomObject
{
}

public class CustomObjectList
{
    public static ObservableCollection<CustomObject> List = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();

    // Instance property
    public CustomObject NonStaticCustomObject { get; set; }

    // Static property
    public static CustomObject StaticCustomObject { get; set; }

    public void OnOpen()
    {

        // This is a reference of the new object added to the collection scoped to the method.
        var newCustomObject = new CustomObject();

        // Add it to the list
        List.Add(newCustomObject);

        // Store as a static reference
        CustomObjectList.StaticCustomObject = newCustomObject;

        // Store as an instance reference
        NonStaticCustomObject = newCustomObject;
    }



    public void OnClose()
    {

    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void UseList()
    {
        var customList = new CustomObjectList();

        customList.OnOpen();

        // We can get access to the static reference like this.
        var itemFromStatic = CustomObjectList.StaticCustomObject;

        // We can get access to the non static reference like this.
        var itemFromInstance = customList.NonStaticCustomObject;
    }
}
```